# What is the best practice using git and hudson with one repository including multiple projects

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, git-submodules

I have raised a similar question before yet after doing some research and bashing my head for a long time , I have concluded that I need some more guidance.

We have currently migrated to GIT from SVN and biggest impact was to our CI Server. Since you can't checkout sub-directories in GIT.

Our repository consists of multiple projects and we like to keep it that way , because every developer creates its own story branch and merges with the main branch after he is done with the story.

On the other hand we can't manage to configure Hudson or Jenkins with our git repository so that we can create separate tasks for each of our subfolders which corresponds to separate maven projects.

I know its advised to use submodules yet , If we configure each maven project as a submodule our sub-branching won't be in the way that we want to be.

It kinda feels like that it should be possible to configure in such way that but couldn't achieved any progress so far.

What is it advised that we should do in such situation?

Comment: Beside, that you already said, you want to keep it: You should use one repository per project, because ... well, then you don't have a mix of projects in your repository ;) It wouldn't change the workflow as far as I can see.

Comment: yeah but having submodules doesnt really have a point, actually they are pretty much useless in this case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @KingCrunch's statement that you should have a separate repo for each project, but if you have to keep your single repo for some reason you could do this:

1. For each Jenkins build, click the Advanced button in the Git section
   and set the Included / Excluded Regions fields so that you only poll
   for changes in the subfolder that contains the code for the project
   being built.
2. Set the Maven build step of your job to pick up the POM file from the appropriate subdirectory.